# space in textarea won't work

Tags: html

If I tap `[space][space]test` in a textarea the space won't show when it's output(space in DBC case works). How to make space in SBC case work in textarea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

same applies if you did it in a html document, multiple spaces are usually collapsed (browser behaviour), but you can fix that by using a non breaking space `&nbsp;`

in php

```
str_replace('  ','&nbsp;&nbsp;');
```

that's 2 for 2

Comment: I just found a better and simpler solution: just wrap the content with<pre></pre> will do the same thing.